# How is code signing done in Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, build, code-signing

I have a script for building my app that is broken since updating to Xcode 4.5. The problem is code signing. When I run the following:

```
/usr/bin/xcrun \
    -sdk iphoneos \
    PackageApplication \
    -v "${BUILD_DIR}/${APPLICATION_NAME}.app" \
    -o "${APP_ARCHIVE}" \
    --sign "${DEVELOPER_ID}"
    --embed "${PROVISIONING_PROFILE}"
```

I get the following error:

> `error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata --sign iPhone Developer: Apple Developer --resource-rules=/var/folders/p5/gfgpv6911ylbs52cnbh2___m0000gq/T/ky9_XtRlRr/Payload/Blah.app/ResourceRules.plist /var/folders/p5/gfgpv6911ylbs52cnbh2___m0000gq/T/ky9_XtRlRr/Payload/Blah.app failed with error 1. Output: /var/folders/p5/gfgpv6911ylbs52cnbh2___m0000gq/T/ky9_XtRlRr/Payload/Blah.app: replacing existing signature`
>
> `codesign_allocate: object:     /private/var/folders/p5/gfgpv6911ylbs52cnbh2___m0000gq/T/ky9_XtRlRr/Payload/Blah.app/Blah malformed object (unknown load command 34)`
>
> `/var/folders/p5/gfgpv6911ylbs52cnbh2___m0000gq/T/ky9_XtRlRr/Payload/Blah.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable`

Something is going wrong with the code signing where it was working fine with Xcode 4.3 before. Can code signing still be done with the same command? Is this "unknown load command" the culprit, and if so, what is it, and how would one go about finding and fixing it?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your time machine.  I'm pretty sure iOS 6 hasn't yet been released.

Comment: @ferson2020, which beta version of Xcode 4.5 are you running?

Comment: I'm running Xcode45-DP4.

Comment: After fiddling with it, I found a solution. I updated by xcode command line tools and ran xcrun without explicitly naming its path (I was running usr/bin/xcrun before) some combination of these two things fixed it for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out upgrading XCode from App Store does NOT automatically upgrade everything.

Go to **Preferences / Downloads** and make sure the latest **Command Line Tools** are installed.

Comment: This happened for me when I upgraded to XCode 5 as well, my script to sign iOS apps started failing with the "object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable". Upgrading the command line tools appears to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

And once you update the cmd restart your mac for better results, I wasted 1 hour on this.